# how to make my logo and company name as responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

kindly let me know how to edit it using HTML and CSS responsively. As if I reduce my screen size it shows different alignment.

```html
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <div id="logo">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.belltele.co.in" 
             target="_blank"><font color="#e5001e">MY COMPANY NAME</font></a>
                 <div class = "img-responsive">
                    <img src="logow.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt=" SORRY" 
             style="float:right">
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: could you share working fiddle or snippet

Comment: Check out media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 4):

I have used a flexbox for responsiveness and vertical alignment.

```css
#logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: #e5001e;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="logo">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.belltele.co.in" target="_blank">MY COMPANY NAME</a>
        <div class="img-responsive">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/50" class="img-responsive" alt="SORRY"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think what he wants is logo to be on the right most side and name of the company to be on the left most side, which can be achieved by further adding `justify-content: space-between;` to `#logo` CSS. :)

Comment: If the right alignment is required, you are absolutely right Karan. Alternatively, margin-left: auto; for img-responsive would work as well.

Comment: i tried it,but heading and logo is not on the page.Only other details are in page if i resize it,i need to do right scroll where only heading i could see in right side ,totally differeent. after my company name logo , i have responsive table,it is in proper form .

Answer (score 0):

try this:
https://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/WOjymd

Add the line height to "sorry" (img-responsive) to align them in the navbar

```
.img-responsive{
  line-height:50px; //(bootstrap default navbar height is 50px)
}
```

If you change the height of the navbar, you also need to adjust this to reflect it

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

add this meta tag

Comment: none of the code is helpful for me.If i add it as above all said,heading alone going wrong in second page

Answer (score 0):

If you want the LOGO to be on the right side always, you can position it absolutely as so:

```
div.image-responsive{
position: absolute;
top: 5px; //add a space of 5px from the top
right: 5px;  //add a space of 5px from the right
}
```

This way the image-responsive div is always on the right side, with gaps of 5px from right, and top